# json.exception.parse_error when calling google::cloud::storage::Client

Tags: c++, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cpp

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-cpp/
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-cpp/blob/master/google/cloud/storage/examples/storage_quickstart.cc

after building all available libraries, run storage_quickstart

```
/home/google-cloud-cpp/build-output/google/cloud/storage/examples/storage_quickstart bucket_name project_id
```

get this

```
Standard C++ exception raised: [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at 1: syntax error - unexpected end of input; expected '[', '{', or a literal
```

error at

```
namespace gcs = google::cloud::storage;
gcs::Client client;
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS` is not set, or is pointing to a file in the wrong format. Hopefully the documentation here:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-cpp/latest/storage/index.html

can help you troubleshoot this.  Feel free to open a bug in the GitHub page if you need more help.

Comment: My environment variable was not set correctly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For what is worth, we merged [#1212](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-cpp/pull/1212) which should produce much better error messages from now on.